# How to check f/s size consumption on /var/lib/kubelet/plugins/kubernetes.io/gce-pd/mounts/XYZ? GCP k8s

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine, kubernetes-pod

How to check f/s size consumption on /var/lib/kubelet/plugins/kubernetes.io/gce-pd/mounts/XYZ? GCP k8s.

I don't have access to log on to cluster to validate, Any kubectl command or any command we run to get the fs size like we run "df" command on linux machines.

Comment: What is the purpose of checking that part of the filesystem ? What are you trying to acheive ?

Comment: Our monitoring system alerts that this mount system is 100% full. Hence need to find which PV is full and act accordingly.